# How to make a method in .NET Core that calculates variables, (database data) and automatically inserts the data into a SQL database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to create a method in my controller class that allows me to calculate values such as average, running totals and so forth from input entered by users and inserts the transformed data into a database. Are there any efficient ways to do this in ASP.NET Core MVC?

I tried pulling input data straight from the read method, which inserts the data into the database but It is not working for all calculations.

I have tried this so far but I am getting a null value error when dividing and a SQL error when running the code shown below.

I tried using the post method in C# shown below and calling it in the insert method so it inserts the data into the database.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Calculate(FuelCalculationDataModel calcFuelDataRequest)
{
    //sets the registration number as the variable 
    var fuel = fuelDbContext.FuelData.Find(calcFuelDataRequest.vehicleregistrationNumber);
    
    if (fuel != null)
    {
        //if registration number is not negative, then individual accumulated kilometres is odometer total
        fuel.accKilometeres = fuelDbContext.FuelData.Select(p => p.odometerTotal).Sum();
        fuel.accLitres = fuelDbContext.FuelData.Select(p => p.filledVolume).Sum();

        //if registration number is not negative, then the refill cost is fuel price multiplied by the filled volume
        fuel.refillCost = fuel.fuelPrice * fuel.filledVolume;

        fuel.consumptionKm = fuel.accKilometeres / fuel.accLitres;
        fuel.consumptionLitres = fuel.accLitres / fuel.accKilometeres;

        fuel.costOfTheKm = (1/fuel.fuelPrice * fuel.consumptionKm);
        // fuel.accLitresTotal = fuelDbContext.FuelData.Select(p => p.accLitres).Sum();
        fuel.accLitresTotal = fuelDbContext.FuelData.Select(p => p.accLitres).Sum();
        fuel.accKilometerTotal = fuelDbContext.FuelData.Select(p => p.accKilometeres).Sum();

        fuel.consumptionKmTotal = fuelDbContext.FuelData.Select(p => p.consumptionKm).Sum();
        fuel.consumptionlitresTotal = await fuelDbContext.FuelData.Select(p => p.consumptionLitres).SumAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: "I have tried this so far but I am getting a null value error when dividing and a SQL error when running the code shown below." - Please provide much more detail. *Exactly* which line fails? What is the precise error? What's the SQL error? (And how are you getting two different errors?)

Comment: Cory,  Can you provide what the value details are in the fuel object?

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? What you wrote loads a single object `fuel` and replaces its fields with the totals of *all* objects. Then it just discards `fuel`

Comment: If you really want the totals for all rows you can use `.GroupBy(_=>1).Select(g=>new { Kilometers=g.Sum(p => p.odometerTotal), Liters=g.Sum(p => p.filledVolume),...});`, although a SQL query would be simpler. If you want rolling totals, or car values compared to total values, it may not be possible to use LINQ at all, while SQL would allow you to use eg `SUM() OVER()` to calculate both rolling totals and overall totals on every row

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that , something can not divide by 0. when try to divide by (x/0), then it generates the exception.

you can try this:

```
    if(fuel.accLitres != 0)

      {
 
           fuel.consumptionKm = fuel.accKilometeres / fuel.accLitres;

      }

      if(fuel.accKilometeres != 0)
      {

          fuel.consumptionLitres = fuel.accLitres / fuel.accKilometeres;
      }
```

hope your problem will solve.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

if I understand the problem there are edge cases where the calculation fail.

As Fazle suggest a division by zero could throw an exception, but inserting a condition to avoid the exception left the field empty.
I suppose that, if you get a null related exception, the property is mapped to a non nullable column to the database.

The problem could be addressed in different ways (based on the fact that its fine for you to have null data in the database or not):

- insert a validation so that you reject invalid data (divider equals to zero) and return a [ValidationProblem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.validationproblem?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
- change the property to be nullable (e.g. from `decimal consumptionLitres` to `decimal? consumptionLitres`, and add related migration to the dbcontext

Anyway I suggest to always insert validation code in your logic to block invalid data as soon as possible and return correct HTTP answer. There are many methods to do it, a simple one is to enrich your model with attributes, more complex could use external libraries as FluentValidation and so on.

see [Model validation in ASP.NET Core MVC and Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0)